# Unity Tilemap making individual falling times

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

The issue is making individual platforms fall when using Tile maps. Currently when player collides, every platform falls rather than individual platforms falling.

Using the Tilemap feature I created multiple "falling platforms". The layer is called Falling Platform(FP). The first platform is created on a different layer as a respawn point. Platforms 2,3 & 4 are on FP.

["Falling Platforms 2,3,4"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6X8O.png) /
[All 3 platforms falling together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAPnb.png)

Inside the Inspector for this layer, I added a RigidBody 2D Component &  Composite Collider 2D. Tilemap Collider 2D has been set to *used by Composite*.

RigidBody 2D is initially set to Kinematic however, a trigger is set to changed to Dynamic when Player collides with object, causing the block to fall.

[Falling platform components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my0W9.png)

A script has been added to FP. Script is working, making the platform fall when player collides with it however, it is applying it to every platform as opposed to setting the script on each individual platform.

Is it possible to have the script run on each separate platform or would I need to make a different layer for each individual platform? I suspect it would then be easier to make a 2D sprite into a prefab and forgo Tile map.

```cs
public class FallingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
           }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.name.Equals ("whiteTile")) {

            Invoke("DropPlatform", 0.2f);
            Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
        }
    }

    void DropPlatform(){
        rb.isKinematic = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, sadly what you are doing will not work.  A Tilemap is *one gameObject*, so making one tile fall will make the whole thing fall. What I have done in the past is drag the tile out you want to fall as a standalone game object and then put my fall logic on that.

Another alternative is you can have separate tilemaps for each falling object, but at that point you might as well make them a separate object in game.

[Here is an example of it used in game.](https://aribaa.itch.io/byte-blaster)